# Picker Unavailable. There was an error while preparing the picker. Please try again later

Tags: swiftui

I got this error when using photo picker, it only appeared occasionally when I swipe down to download more photos or tap the search box.

[image: Error]

```
2020-09-29 21:20:21.268201+0700 Widgets[16820:1808484] [lifecycle] [u 154CDFD9-7610-4333-99DE-0FDA8CF04E77:m (null)] [com.apple.mobileslideshow.photospicker(1.0)] Connection to plugin interrupted while in use.
2020-09-29 21:20:21.268855+0700 Widgets[16820:1808408] [lifecycle] [u 154CDFD9-7610-4333-99DE-0FDA8CF04E77:m (null)] [com.apple.mobileslideshow.photospicker(1.0)] Connection to plugin invalidated while in use.
2020-09-29 21:20:21.268581+0700 Widgets[16820:1806436] [Picker] Picker failed with error: Error Domain=PXErrorDomain Code=-1 "PHPickerViewController did receive interruption." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=PHPickerViewController did receive interruption.}
2020-09-29 21:20:21.293818+0700 Widgets[16820:1806436] viewServiceDidTerminateWithError:: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={Message=Service Connection Interrupted}
```

How do i fix it? :(

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this?  I am getting the same console error messages, except the on screen message is now "Unable to Load Items" with a button below that says "Try Again". Tapping the button loads the items.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same errors and was able to resolve my issue by moving the .sheet modifier (for the picker) from a List row to the List itself.